# Inferior limit of a succession of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

I read that the inferior limit of a succession of points $x_n$ is defined as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\inf_{m \geq n}x_n).$$
However I didn't find anything on how is defined the inferior limit of a succession of functions (that appears for example in Fatou's lemma): basically, I don't understand what metric I must consider on the space of functions, so that I can apply the definition. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is just pointwise $\liminf$

Comment: I.e. $(\liminf f_n)(x):=\liminf(f_n(x))$ or $f(x)=\liminf(f_n(x))$ where $f=\liminf f_n$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now